# Weld + WildFly Swarm errors

Tags: weld, wildfly-swarm

I am trying to get CDI to work in WildFly Swarm, but Weld keeps throwing errors, even on a minimal toy example, see: https://github.com/delenius/weld-test

I am keeping things as simple as possible, and following the recommended way of setting up WildFly Swarm, using http://wildfly-swarm.io/generator/.

I am using version 2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT.

I have tried bean-discovery-mode="all", as mentioned in another stackoverflow issue.

This is the output I get from `java -jar` (after which it exits):

```
$ java -jar target/wildfly-weld-test-swarm.jar
2017-12-12 11:56:36,584 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:logging:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,593 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:         JAX-RS with JAXB - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs-jaxb:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,593 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:bean-validation:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi-config:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:cdi:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                  Elytron - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:elytron:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:transactions:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:undertow:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,594 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (main) WFSWARM0013: Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          org.wildfly.swarm:jaxrs:2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT
2017-12-12 11:56:36,670 WARNING [ServiceLoader] (main) Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.cdi.config.deployment.InjectConfigViewExtension
2017-12-12 11:56:38,188 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
2017-12-12 11:56:38,286 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Swarm 2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
2017-12-12 11:56:38,324 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFSWARM0019: Install MSC service for command line args: []
2017-12-12 11:56:38,919 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.6.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:38,952 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 14) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
2017-12-12 11:56:38,957 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 15) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2017-12-12 11:56:38,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 20) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:38,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2017-12-12 11:56:38,979 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:38,986 INFO  [org.xnio] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:39,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2017-12-12 11:56:39,033 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:39,070 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
2017-12-12 11:56:39,147 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final starting
2017-12-12 11:56:39,247 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2017-12-12 11:56:39,299 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8080
2017-12-12 11:56:39,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
2017-12-12 11:56:39,373 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Swarm 2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 1264ms - Started 122 of 130 services (20 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2017-12-12 11:56:39,824 INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.runtime.deployer] (main) deploying wildfly-weld-test.war
2017-12-12 11:56:39,849 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "wildfly-weld-test.war" (runtime-name: "wildfly-weld-test.war")
2017-12-12 11:56:40,263 WARN  [org.jboss.as.dependency.private] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0018: Deployment "deployment.wildfly-weld-test.war" is using a private module ("org.jboss.jts") which may be changed or removed in future versions without notice.
2017-12-12 11:56:40,275 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment wildfly-weld-test.war
2017-12-12 11:56:40,364 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final
2017-12-12 11:56:40,482 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,516 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2017-12-12 11:56:40,848 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Validator] (MSC service thread 1-5) WELD-001471: Interceptor method setupFactories defined on class org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer.setupFactories(StandaloneXMLParserProducer.java:0)
  StackTrace
2017-12-12 11:56:40,860 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-weld-test.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."wildfly-weld-test.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
  at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)

    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:362)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:158)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:501)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

2017-12-12 11:56:40,864 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (main) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: (("deployment" => "wildfly-weld-test.war")) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
  at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
"}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,865 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (main) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "wildfly-weld-test.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
  at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
"}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,881 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
2017-12-12 11:56:40,908 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment wildfly-weld-test.war (runtime-name: wildfly-weld-test.war) in 42ms
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main) org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,910 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:473)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:744)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,911 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:132)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:85)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,912 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2017-12-12 11:56:40,916 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
2017-12-12 11:56:40,918 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0]:8080
2017-12-12 11:56:40,920 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 1.4.18.Final stopping
2017-12-12 11:56:40,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Swarm 2017.12.0-SNAPSHOT (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) stopped in 8ms
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (main) WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container internal shut down
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 ERROR [stderr] (main) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,932 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:132)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:85)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,933 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:473)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:744)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 7 more
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
2017-12-12 11:56:40,934 ERROR [stderr] (main) Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:132)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:85)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,935 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:301)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:174)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:107)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deploy(Unknown Source)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.deploy(Swarm.java:473)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:744)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 7 more
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main) Caused by: org.wildfly.swarm.container.DeploymentException: WFSWARM0004: Deployment failed: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"wildfly-weld-test.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)     Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type DeploymentContext with qualifiers @Default
2017-12-12 11:56:40,936 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext
2017-12-12 11:56:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.jaxrs.runtime.DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.deploymentContext(DefaultApplicationDeploymentProcessor.java:0)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (main) "}}
2017-12-12 11:56:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (main)   at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeDeployer.deploy(RuntimeDeployer.java:296)
2017-12-12 11:56:40,937 ERROR [stderr] (main)   ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working by using the released version 2017.12.0 and removing the beans.xml

Comment: With version 2017.12, I get: [ERROR] Plugin org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:2017.12.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:jar:2017.12.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: However, with 2017.11.0, it does indeed work, despite what I said in the original problem description (edited now). So it seems to be a problem just with the latest SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: Glad it's sorted now